# Convert RedirectMatch to RewriteRule with condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up a 301 redirect for my old permalink structure on WordPress to a postname structure, but without affecting any other addon domains hosted in subdirectories of the main domain.

Yoast provides this code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://www.example.com/$4
```

The problem is this affects all addon domains that I host in subdirectories of the root domain. So I think I need to change this to mod_rewrite so I can use a condition that will make it affect only the main domain. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^some-address / [L,R=301]
```

How do I convert the RedirectMatch to the proper RewriteRule?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about your sample URLs that you wish to redirect. However, maybe this code would help you to figure out a correct RewriteRule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://www.example.com/$4 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

or

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://www.example.com/$4 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

[This tool](https://regex101.com/r/OXhLjD/1) might help you to do your regular expression for the RewriteRule:

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression in your RedirectMatch would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

Every time you make a change in `.htaccess` file, you may want to clear your browsing history, and test it to see if it would work.

Comment: Thank you. The path that I'm trying to rewrite is the default WordPress permalink structure, which is /year/monthnum/day/postname/ to just /postname/. This is the RedirectMatch code that Yoast provides for such a rewrite, but it doesn't take into account the condition of a particular domain (so it doesn't affect subdirectory domains). It seems that I need the RewriteCond to be something like:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]`